# WordPress can't AJAX to ASP.NET.Core Web Application on same machine

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wordpress, ubuntu, asp.net-web-api

First of all, I know there's much better ways for achieving this, but it's a school project so I have no choice but to do this like our teachers want...

We got a virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.04) that runs a WordPress server. This same virtual machine also runs an ASP.NET.Core Web Application.

Basically, when someone fills in a form on our WordPress website, we send the user input via AJAX to a route on our Web API (which then sends RabbitMQ messages with the data, but this is not important).

Web Application Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("reservation")]
    public int Create([FromBody]MyForm f)
    {
        //Send RabbitMQ messages with form data
    }
}
```

AJAX code on WordPress:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    method: "post",
    data: jQuery("#myForm").serialize(),
    url: "http://localhost:65443/api/values/reservation",
    succes: function()
    { console.log("Success"); }
});
```

When I run the Web Application with `dotnet run`, it says it's listening on `localhost:65443` and I can perfectly "interact" with my Web API via `curl` commando.

But submitting the form on WordPress logs this error:
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. 
I don't get it, WordPress is running on the same machine as the Web Application so sending an AJAX request to `localhost:65443` should work fine just like the `curl` commando :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is WordPress site hosted on a different port?, if yes did you enable CORS?

Comment: Yes WordPress is hosted on a different port, what is CORS and how do I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Default Model Binder doesn't know how to bind the serialized `myForm` form to the `MyForm` class.

Could you construct JSON data manually, and send as JSON? E.g.

```
var data = { firstName: txtFirstName.val() };
              ^^^^^^
      Property inside MyForm class


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:65443/api/values/reservation',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is not the json, it's the url... WordPress can't access localhost:65443 but it's the same machine so it should work...

Comment: Could you create a `HttpGet` method in Web API, and access it from WordPress site? I would like to see the issue is related to a specific http verb only.

Answer (score 0):

In your Web API method remove `[FromBody]` as this will force Web API to read a `MyForm` type from the request body as JSON and you are posting FormData `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("reservation")]
    public int Create(MyForm f)
    {
        //Send RabbitMQ messages with form data
    }
}
```

Also, you will need to make sure that  CORS support is configured in your Web API project.

To configure CORS support at the global level, first, install the CORS package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors
```

In the `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs` add the CORS services.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

And then open `Startup.cs` file under root folder and add below configuration at the beginning of `Configure` method.

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5901").AllowAnyMethod());
```

*http://localhost:5901* >> should refer to your WordPress website.

And in `ConfigureServices` method at `startup.cs` add the CORS services.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

Check [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for more

Comment: I added the package, but there's no "App_Start" folder in my project. I think I have an ASP.Net.Core MVC project. I have appsettings.json, Sartup.cs, Properties > launchSettings.json

Comment: What should I put instead of http://example.com? I'm guessing something with "http://localhost:80" but I don't know if 80 is the right port?

Comment: Your WordPress website, Also check my answer updates

Comment: I think my WordPress runds on port 80, I added all the code but I still get the error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED :(

Comment: the other guess is that your Web API is not running correctly or run in another port

Comment: As you can see on the screenshots:

-Web api is listening on port 65443 https://prnt.sc/jay8ay
-Port information sheet from our teacher which says WordPress runs on port 80 https://prnt.sc/jay9f6
-So that's what I used https://prnt.sc/jay8jl

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error from browser console and try to show with browser URL

Comment: Here's the error: http://prntscr.com/jb2z7p And this is my script tag that fires the ajax: http://prntscr.com/jb2zsu

Comment: Here's another screenshot of the error "Network" tab https://prnt.sc/jb321e

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Still not working :((( Does it play a role that I just run the Web application with "dotnet run"?

Comment: Please share your form HTML and `MyForm` class content

Comment: MyForm has the exact same properties as the HTML form, I know the `name` attribute has to match the name of the property like `<input type="text" name="Firstname">` must be mapped to `public string Firstname { get; set; }`

Comment: can you share `<form>` tag attributes

Comment: Form: http://prntscr.com/jcdbbw   Ajax script: http://prntscr.com/jcdbjz